# Remote connections inside Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, networking

I am trying to open a connection inside my C# MVC.NET application, to retrieve some data and show them on a view. Everything works good when developing on localhost, using Visual Studio Community 2015 and its integrated IIS Express server.

When I deploy my application onto an Azure App Service, network connections stop working, I noticed my application becomes unable to reach outside network directly (i.e. I cannot use SSH.NET to give a command to a server or retrieve data). Application is still working (views are rendered/other controller actions execute perfectly) but when I request a network connection anywhere inside the app, failure happens.

Also, opening App Service console in Azure dashboard, I've noticed that I'm even  unable to ping any host due to a missing IP driver.

What are the missing steps in my deployment or what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Azure App Service is different from Azure VM, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: *Ping* doesn't seem to be possible in Azure console (probably for security reasons). When using the *curl* command you should be able to connect to other sites however, thus proving you're not locked in.

Is the SSH application also running on Azure? SSH default runs on port 22, while only port 80 and 443 are open for Azure App Services.

Comment: _"(i.e. I cannot use SSH.NET to give a command to a server or retrieve data)."_ -- right so can you `tcpping dest.server.com:22` from the Kudu console?

Comment: @HaithamShaddad I would like to make a button that connects to a server, retrieves some results and print them on a page. Or a button that connects via ssh to a server, open a tunnel or issue commands to a server.

Comment: @evilSnobu tcpping gives "Connection timed out", that is the same error my libraries are giving.

Comment: Is your destination accepting connections from your Azure Web App's outgoing public IP address? - http://i.imgur.com/9QYMPI5.png

Comment: @evilSnobu Yes, there are absolutely no restrictions

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to a VM or a on prem resource you need to set up Virtual Network to do this. As explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/). You can not directly make connection to resource directly outside the network.

Comment: I want my Azure App connects to a remote service. I don't want to connect to the Azure App or VM from outside. I need only that my app, inside a controller action, connects to a server and retrieves informations, or connects to an ssh server to issue commands or open port forwardings.

Comment: I think this will explain much more better   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late in the party but here is my two cent.

You should check that if the application pool user of your app service have access rights of the network/machine you are trying to connect because when you execute in the dev environment it works because I think the user on IIS would have rights to access the test network/machine.

P.S. To achieve the same you can create a parameterised console application and trigger it using a hosted simple API on the remote machine.